# Checkbox must be checked for particular id

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is a jquery code that would run when a check box is clicked... But right now I need to assign an id for the input type ,so that this function should work work only for that particular id, what could be the solution?

```
<!-- HTML PART -->

<li><input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' value='1' checked="checked"  />  </li>

<!-- JQUERY PART -->

 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
 var count=$("input:checked").length;
 if(count==5)
 {
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled",true);

}
 else
 {
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled",false);
}
save_skills();
get_skill();
});
```

Comment: why can't you use `#checkbox` as a selector ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstood.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    if (this.id == 'your-custom-id') {
       // your code
    }
});
```

Or

```
if ('#your-id').click(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `id="checkbox"` to the desired checkbox tag and don't use that id anywhere else in the page, then you can use this jQuery to target just that checkbox.

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: i have used it but now its not working. is there any way to pass both id and input[type=checkbox]

Comment: yes you can - http://jsfiddle.net/ba5E6/ , but why http://jsfiddle.net/ba5E6/1  ?

Comment: There's no point in using anything other than #checkbox in the jQuery selector if you do your HTML properly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at following code too, if it is what you want
HTML code

```
<li><input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' value='1'  />  </li>
<li><input id='checkbox1' type='checkbox' value='2'   />  </li> 
<li><input id='checkbox2' type='checkbox' value='3'  />  </li> 
<li><input id='checkbox3' type='checkbox' value='4'   />  </li> 
<li><input id='checkbox4' type='checkbox' value='5' />  </li> 
<div id="count"></div>
```

and the js

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr("id") == "checkbox2") {

        $('#count').html("this is what i want");
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);

        $('#count').html('No this is not');
    }

});
});
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/aZ5wv/7/
Hope this will help you in some way